# Proof that subtracting a finite set from an infinite one retains cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Formally put: If $M$ is an infinite set, and $E$ a finite subset $E\subset M$, then $|M\setminus E| = |M|$ (cardinality is unchanged when removing a finite number of elements).

It is readily obvious that
$$
(M\setminus E) \cup E = M
$$

Since $(M\setminus E)$ and $E$ are obviously disjoint, then the following rule applies:
$$|(M\setminus E) \cup E| = |(M\setminus E)| + |E|$$

Inserting this on the left hand side of the above...
$$|(M\setminus E)| + |E| = |M|$$
Since $E$ was finite, it must have some finite cardinality number $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$$|(M\setminus E)| + |E| = |(M\setminus E)| + k = |M| \iff |(M\setminus E)| = |M| - k$$

And since $|M|$ was an infinite set, subtracting any natural number from its cardinal number does not change it. Thus the $-k$ may be omitted, and the proof is done.

This was just the best I could cobble together from some basic set theory and reasoning. But I've seen some uses on the internet - without references! - of a rule like $|A\cup B| = max\{|A|,|B|\}$ which applies in the case of infinite sets? I haven't been able to find a reference for this, but I can see how it would be used here.

Any way, is the above sufficient? Is the rule I used assured to work here?

Comment: You are going to need some axiom of choice at some point in the proof. I think the easiest way is to show there is an injection of $\omega$ in your infinite set and then observe that $\omega$ minus an infinite set has same cardinality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do, by definition, is find a bijection from $M$ to $M\setminus E.$ The idea that you take away a finite number of elements from an infinite set and it can't stop it from being infinite is not a bad heuristic, but how do you know it doesn't decrease its cardinality to a smaller, but still infinite, cardinality? You are effectively assuming what needs to be proven.

The way we establish a bijection is we use the fact that such a bijection can be readily obtained for a countably infinite set. So let $M_0$ be a countably infinite set such that $E\subseteq M_0\subseteq M$ and then prove there is a bijection between $M_0$ and $M_0\setminus E,$ which can then be extended to a bijection between $M$ and $M\setminus E.$

The existence of such an $M_0$ actually requires the axiom of choice, so this whole affair is surprisingly nontrivial. To tie this to what I said initially, it is really quite literally the case that in the absence of the axiom of choice it is consistent that $M\setminus E$ could have a strictly smaller cardinality from $M$ (though still infinite).

---

More detail on the two steps outlined above.

1. We can construct a bijection between $M_0$ and $M_0\setminus E$ recursively. Identify $M_0$ with the natural numbers. Let $f(0)$ be the least element of $\mathbb N\setminus E$ and let $f(n+1)$ be the least element of $(\mathbb N\setminus E)\setminus\{f(0),\ldots, f(n)\}.$
2. We can construct $M_0$ recursively using the axiom of choice. Let $X_0 = E,$ and let $X_{n+1} = X_n\cup \{a\}$ for some arbitrary element $a\in M\setminus X_n$ (which always exists since, by induction, $X_n$ is finite). Then take $M_0 = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} X_n.$

Note, the second argument uses dependent choice, but this is overkill: the statement every infinite set has a countably infinite subset is actually strictly weaker than countable choice, and it's not too hard to find a proof using only countable choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still a little hazy on the final step(s).

Having constructed the bijection between $M_0$ and $M_0\setminus E$ I don't see how it extends to $M$ in its entirety. We have the following set inclusions $$M=(M_0\setminus E)\cup E \cup (M\setminus M_0)$$, but this sort of cancels out the E any way, and you wind up with just $|M| = |M_0 \cup (M\setminus M_0)|$. I'm sorry I don't quite see how the $M_0$ and $M_0\setminus E$ extends to the potentially larger cardinality of $M$.

Comment: @Woodenplank You have $E\subseteq M_0\subseteq M.$ Let $f:M_0\to M_0\setminus E $ be a bijection. Then let $g(x)$ be $f(x)$ for $x\in M_0$ and be $x$ for $x\in M\setminus M_0.$ Then, $g$ is a bijection $M\to M\setminus E.$

Comment: Necro'ing the thread a bit... But for $f: M_0 \mapsto M_0\setminus E$, in the way you've defined it, does it not assume that $M_0\setminus E$ is infinite any way? I.e. that we can't run out of elements in $M_0\setminus E$ to map to from $M_04?

Comment: @Woodenplank It is infinite. If not, then $M_0$ would be the union of two finite sets, so finite. Note this part doesn’t rely on countability or AC in any way: it’s always the case that the difference between an infinite set and a finite set is infinite.